# Not able to pass scope to dialog in angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I am displaying a list of images using Angular.

When an image is clicked I want to display a dialog with the image and more info.

So when opening the modal I need to pass the scope, or at least, the image.

Note: I am using [ngDialog](http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/) for the popup.

```
  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService, ngDialog) {

    $scope.model = {
      images: [],
      loading: false
    }

    var load = function () {
      $scope.model.loading = true;
      ImageService.GetList($scope.model.pages.instagram)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images)
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
        .finally(function () {
          $scope.model.loading = false
        });;
    }

    $scope.open = function (image) {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<p>my template {{image.Key}} </p>',
        plain: true,
        scope: $scope
      });
    };


    load();

  });

  <div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController">
    <div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" data-ng-click="open(image)"/>
  </div>
```

The images are displayed and the dialog is opened on click ...

However, somehow, I am not able to access the scope inside the template.

The following works:

```
    $scope.open = function (image) {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<p>my template' + image.Key + '</p>',
        plain: true
      });
    };
```

But this does not work:

```
    $scope.open = function (image) {
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<p>my template {{image.Key}} </p>',
        plain: true,
        scope: $scope
      });
    };
```

Does anyone has any idea why?

I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: Well, if you have the html for the dialog included as a child of the ImageController, you will be able to access the scope of the controller. Another method you can use is to use $broadcast/$emit to push data down and up.

Comment: When you say " if you have the html for the dialog included as a child of the ImageController" you mean as my example 1? Because that is working ...

Comment: I created my second example by reading the following: https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#scope-object So I am not sure what am I missing ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change your open method to following..

```
  $scope.open = function (image) {
      var newScope = $scope.$new();
      newScope.image = image;
      ngDialog.open({
        template: '<p>my template {{image.Key}} </p>',
        plain: true,
        scope: newScope
      });
    };
```

This should work ...

Answer (score 1):

The best way that works for me is without scope. just use data attribute:

```
 $scope.open = function (image) {          
                  ngDialog.openConfirm({
                  template: 'views/alertTemplate.html'
                  showClose: false,
                  data: {
                    image: image,
                  }
                });  
            }
```

and in your template file:

```
<div class="alert-dialog-container">
  <div class="alert-dialog-body">
    <p ng-bind-html="ngDialogData.image"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="alert-dialog-footer">
    <button ng-click="confirm()">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```